# How many light novel volumes are covered in the "Papa no Iukoto wo Kikinasai!" anime?

Tags: listen-to-me-girls-i-am-your-father

The anime ends with

> the rights to the Takanashi residence being transferred to Yuuta, and them moving back into the house.

The light novels are still ongoing.

How many volumes did the anime cover? If I were to pick up the light novels from where the anime ended, from what volume should I begin reading?

Comment: anyone has answer to this question? I have googled a little bit and I only found out that the OVA is adapted from the last volume of the light novel

Answer (score 1):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%91%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84!#%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1),

> Using **volume 1 *and* volume 7** (the episode where Yuuta's doing daily life with the three sisters at an apartment in Hachioji) from the original work (light novel) as the base for the *anime's original story*, original characters were also added. Also, there are some different settings between the anime and the light novel, like
>
> > the Takanashi couple died instead of missing.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Since volume 7 is a collection of short stories and the anime's story is considered original, I can't really suggest continuing from volume 2, but instead just start from volume 1.

---

Regarding the 2 OVAs, I think both of them are original stories. Both OVAs were included as a bonus for the limited edition of volume 13 and 18 (the last volume), but Wikipedia doesn't mention if they adapted from them instead.